# Responsive background with maintained aspect ratio

Tags: jquery, responsive-design, slideshow, cycle, jquery-cycle

I'm using Malsup's Cycle 2 to create a background slideshow with corresponding sliding text in a separate div. I've got some simple markup here, but can't seem to get the image to crop so that it will always be 100% of the browser height (if you make a thin window you will see the red on the bottom).

Maybe the solution is jQuery or CSS — everything I see suggests using `height:auto` on the image and the parent div, to no avail.

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/QkkX3/2/)

```
<div id="background" class="cycle-slideshow" 
                     data-cycle-fx="scrollHorz" 
                     data-cycle-timeout="2000"
                     data-cycle-slides="> div"
>
    <div style="background:#fcc">
        <img src="http://stoptraining.me/staged/IMG_1402.jpg">
    </div>
    <div style="background:#cfc">
        <img src="http://stoptraining.me/staged/IMG_1403.jpg">
    </div>
</div>

<div class="center">
    <div id="text" class="cycle-slideshow" 
                   data-cycle-fx="fade" 
                   data-cycle-timeout="2000"
                   data-cycle-slides="> div"
    >
        <div>
            <h2>Title</h2>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor ...</p>
        </div>
        <div>
            <p>Mel eu pertinax ...
        </div>
        <div>
            <p>Utinam electram pertinacia ...
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
body, html {
    background: red;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    height: auto;
    width: 100%;
}
#background {
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    z-index: 99;
    overflow: hidden;
}
#background div {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    background-size: cover;
    overflow: hidden;
}
#background div img {
}
img {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}
#text {
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
    z-index: 99;
}
.center {
    background: white;
    padding: 200px 0 0 0;
    width: 400px;
    overflow: auto;
    min-height: 1000px;
    margin: auto;
    z-index: 9999;
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is currently no CSS styles that will help any element maintain its aspect ratio based on which side is larger; hence, you will have to resort to using JavaScript.

Here's a working [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/QkkX3/11/), which accomplishes what you are wanting.

---

The above solution contains a few modifications from your original...

## CSS:

**Remove:**

```
#background div img {
}
img{
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}
```

**Change:**

```
#background {
    /* ... */
    /* make sure width and height are 100%! */
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    /* ... */
}
#background div {
    /* ... */
    /* make sure width and height are 100%! */
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    /* ... */
}
```

**Add:**

```
#background div img.wider {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}
#background div img.higher {
    width: auto;
    height: 100%;
}
```

## **JavaScript:**

```js
var imgWidth = 1600;
var imgHeight = 1067;
var imgRatio = imgWidth / imgHeight;

$(ResizeBackground); // call on initialize
$(window).resize(ResizeBackground); // and on resize

function ResizeBackground() {
    var div = $('#background');
    var divWidth = div.width();
    var divHeight = div.height();

    // if the div's ratio is higher than the image, it means that
    // the div is wider than the image (and the background will be seen on the sides).
    // Else, the div is higher and will display the background on the bottom.

    // this condition will change the images proportion to always fill the background.
    if (divWidth / divHeight > imgRatio) {
        div.find('img').removeClass('higher').addClass('wider');
    } else {
        div.find('img').removeClass('wider').addClass('higher');
    }
}
```

---

## **Update**

In order to center the images *while* having them proportionally sized, you have to use the following calculations:

```
var $imgs = div.find('img');

if (divRatio > imgRatio) {
    $imgs.each(function () {
        var $this = $(this);
        // set a negative top margin (and move the image up)
        $this.css('margin-top', -Math.abs(div.height() - $this.outerHeight()) / 2);
    });
} else {
    $imgs.each(function () {
        var $this = $(this);
        // set a negative left margin (and move the image to the left)
        $this.css('margin-left', -Math.abs(div.width() - $this.outerWidth()) / 2);
    });
}
```

I've updated [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/QkkX3/22/) slightly, please take a look at it and see the differences marked with `// NEW!!` from [the old one](http://jsfiddle.net/QkkX3/11/).

Comment: This doesn't seem to be resizing once going smaller than the original image size in WebKit. Any solutions?

Comment: Maybe I don't understand what you're experiencing - I just tried the [jsFiddle above](http://jsfiddle.net/QkkX3/11/) in `Chrome 26.0.1410.43 m` and in `Internet Explorer 10`, and I see it works as expected. Can you elaborate some more?

Comment: I made a mistake here, working fine in that regard. However, is there a way to have the image centered if cropped? Right now—when cropped with a long vertical window, the image aligns left and the center of the image is hidden outside the right of the screen.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Ideally it'd show as much of the image as possible (always showing 100% height, and cropping off the & centering horizontal overflow.

Comment: @RooWM I've updated my answer. Please take a look at the **`Update`** section.

Comment: This is actually really useful. Although, I'm currently looking at the code running outside of JS fiddle and am seeing that the two images have different margin-tops. When the margin-tops are both the same on both images, it works perfect, but when they vary, you get the background color showing on one of the images. Why is that?

Comment: @richie The code provided expects all of the images to be the exact same dimensions. There may be additional work required to calculate the *current* image's aspect ratio, instead of calculating it only once.