# Cycle2 centered with responsive height

Tags: jquery, slideshow, jquery-cycle2, responsive-slides

I use Cycle 2 Plugin.
I'm trying to make a centered slideshow with responsive height.

http://jsfiddle.net/Tancrede/gnH9H/4/

```
.slideshow {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    z-index: 1000;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.slideshow img {
    width: auto;
    height: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    opacity: 0;
    filter:alpha(opacity=0);
}
```

I would like this slideshow to work nicely and smoothly.
The major points are that the images will have different sizes but they'll all be 100% of the viewport and they have to be centered (even to be crop if the viewport is too small).

I've seen this proposition which seems to work (I don't know how to adapt this solution to my problem):

[Responsive background with maintained aspect ratio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15576514/responsive-background-slideshow-with-maintained-aspect-ratio-malsup-cycle2)

But I'm only interested in the height, I'm not looking for a real full screen.

My guess is that the solution is to use javascript but I don't know where to start…

Answer (score 0):

Some time passed since you've asked this, but I was running into a similar situation and wanted to add my solution. I've edited your Fiddle a bit to make it work the way I think you intend it to. No need for some extra javascript (at least not in my testing environment).

http://jsfiddle.net/tvgemert/gnH9H/8/

Setting html,body height to 100% does the trick:

```
body,html {
    margin: 0px;
    background-color: red;
    height: 100%;
}
```